# CCNet multiple git repository timeout exception

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net

We have the following setup:

- Win 7 Professional 64 bit
- CCNet v1.6.7981.1
- msysgit v1.7.9-preview20120201

Our Git server is installed on another machine running Ubuntu server 64 bit. 
CCNet windows service runs with an administrator account and use ssh to access the Ubuntu git server.
When performing a forced build we have no problems, getting source and builds are fine. It is when it runs on a time trigger we get the following exceptions:

```
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation has timed out.
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute(ProcessInfo processInfo)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Git.GitFetch(IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Git.CreateUpateLocalRepository(IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Git.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.MultiSourceControl.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModificationsWithLogging(ISourceControl sc, IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModifications(ISourceControl sourceControl, IIntegrationResult lastBuild, IIntegrationResult thisBuild)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
```

our ccnet projects work with multiple git repositories, a sample config looks like this:

```
<sourcecontrol type="multi">
      <sourceControls>
        <git>
          <repository>git@somerepo.git</repository>
          <executable>$(gitcmdpath)</executable>
          <timeout units="minutes">10</timeout>
        </git>
        <git>
          <repository>git@somerepo2.git</repository>
          <executable>$(gitcmdpath)</executable>
          <timeout units="minutes">10</timeout>
          <workingDirectory>c:\somerepo2</workingDirectory>
        </git>
      </sourceControls>
    </sourcecontrol>
```

We have several ccnet projects that utilize the same set of repositories (checked out to different folders though) and they all fail the same way when there is no code changes. I do happen to set the interval trigger to the same length hence they are all checking the repositories roughly at the same time. Can this be why they time out? I also cannot find anything that refer to this from ccnet.log to debug this.

Any help welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a workaround at the moment by putting continuous builds into one queue and full builds into another. continuous builds are based on source control modifications at a 30sec interval, while full builds are once a day so they are now separated. I have this implemented for about 2 weeks now with no problem.